# Which folders to upload to code repository if uploading from Windows but code was made on Mac OS X?

Tags: linux, windows, macos, svn, repository

The source code was made on Mac OS X and when I open it on Windows or Linux, I see 2 folders.

[image]

Now, shall I upload both from Windows/Linux or I can omit `_MACOSX` folder?

These 2 folders are not visible on Mac OS X and I would not like to litter SVN nor to make problems to MAC OS X users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely you've compressed folder on the Mac, and when you unzipped in windows appear to you.
It is created by Apple so spotlight can search the directory zip easy and faster.

To avoid this, there is an excellent application called [YemuZip](http://www.yellowmug.com/yemuzip/), which lets you create compressed files without added undesirable. Just drag the files to the window we want zipear and remember to select `PC Compatible` in the window that appears.

Comment: Yes I got it zipped, you're right. What's the solution? Can you edit your reply?